# I can't set left and top style property on ajaxtoolkit htmleditorextender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I can't set left and top style property on ajaxtoolkit htmleditorextender..

it refers to a TargetControlID like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2"  style="position:relative;left:100px;top:80px" runat="server" Height="228px" Width="483px"></asp:TextBox>
```

but once the extender is added

the textbox loses it's position

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Place your textbox into div container with defined class attribute and add css class definition as below:

```
 .containerClass .ajax__html_editor_extender_container
 {
      position: relative;
      left: 100px;
      top: 80px;
 }
```